# Existence of a certain basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V be a finite dimensional k-vector space and let f: V → V be a k-linear map. Show that there exists a basis $\{e_i\}$ such that

\begin{equation}
    f(e_i)= \sum_{j=i}^{n} \alpha{_i}{_j} e_j
\end{equation}

Comment: What is $\alpha_{i j}$ ?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense as stated. Every $f$ can be written like this once a basis has been chosen, buy the coefficients $\alpha_{ij}$ depend on the basis.

Comment: I agree with Ivo, perhaps you mean a basis of $V$ extended from a basis of $f[V]$?

Comment: I'm confused. Every element of $V$ is a linear combination of the $e_i,$ so $f(e_i)$ will be, too. We need more information, here. I'm with Gribouillis, what are the $\alpha_{ij}?$

Comment: I was wondering about the wording of the question too; I just copied it directly from a homework assignment. I assumed the first subscript of alpha was related to which basis vector you were mapping while the second subscript was related to which basis vector the coefficient was next to. I need to email my professor about this since I'm still confused.

Comment: I also agree with Ivo. My typing speed is almost non-existent, so I guess he and I were responding about the same time.

Comment: I'll post an update once I hear back from my professor.

Comment: @fosterc4 The first step is always to understand the question. Don't look for an answer as long as you don't understand the question.

Comment: I thought I did. lol

Comment: Okay, so the mistake was in the sum. I read it as j=1 to n when it's supposed to be j=i to n.

Comment: So if n=3, $e_3$ would get mapped to some scalar multiple of itself while $e_2$ would get mapped to a linear combination of $e_2$ and $e_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true as stated. Let $\Bbb{k} = \Bbb{R}$ and consider the linear map $f : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ given by $$f(x,y) = (y,-x)$$

and assume there is a basis $\{e_1, e_2\}$ such that $$f(e_1) = \alpha_{11} e_1 + \alpha_{21}e_2, \quad f(e_2) = \alpha_{22}e_2.$$

If $e_2 = (x,y)$ then $$(y,-x) = f(x,y) =\alpha_{22}(x,y) \implies \begin{cases} y= \alpha_{22}x,\\ \alpha_{22}y = -x \end{cases}$$
so $\alpha_{22}^2 x = -x$ which implies $x = 0$ since $\alpha_{22} \in \Bbb{R}$. Hence $y = \alpha_{22}x = 0$ as well so $e_2= 0$ which is a contradiction. Therefore there is no such basis.

The background is that the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
is not similar to a **real** lower triangular matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} \alpha_{11} & 0 \\ \alpha_{21} & \alpha_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$
since the diagonal elements would have to be the eigenvalues $\pm i$.

Comment: What if we assume that k is algebraically closed?

Comment: @fosterc4 Then the answer is yes, you can prove it as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition, or you can take a lower diagonal Jordan normal form over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate.